# VB.NET 2010 Passing Picture from OpenFile Dialog Box to another form

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a loan program that opens a Custom Form Dialog Box, you choose the picture, click open and then need to pass it to another form to use after hitting OK from the Dialog Box. This is my code when I click the Logo File button from my custom Dialog Form.

The Form is called Dialog Form and I need to send the picture to the NewLoanCaculatorForm to populate a picture area in the form.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogoFile.Click

Dim mystream As Stream = Nothing

    'Open the File to pickup icon for Loan Calculator
    Dim OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog

    'Set up and display the open File Dialog
    With OpenFileDialog1
        'Begin in the current Directory
        .InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        .Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    End With

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Try
            mystream = OpenFileDialog1.OpenFile()
            If (mystream IsNot Nothing) Then
                ' I believe the coded goes here but I'm stuck 
            End If
        Catch Ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot read file from disk. Original error: " & Ex.Message)
        Finally
            ' Check this again, since we need to make sure we didn't throw an exception on open. 
            If (mystream IsNot Nothing) Then
                mystream.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually do things like this:

Create global variable in the DialogForm:

```
Public Property sPath as String
```

or

```
Public Property imgLogo as Image
```

To get the Image do this:

```
imgLogo = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
```

Or simply do:

```
sPath = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
```

instead of

```
mystream = OpenFileDialog1.OpenFile()
```

Then when you have done this you close the form by clicking the OK button or whatever you call it.

Then in your main form NewLoanCaculatorForm where you call DialogForm you simply do:

```
img = DialogForm.imgLogo
```

or

```
path = DialogForm.sPath
img = Image.FromFile(path)
```

Depending on which way you stored the info in the DialogForm.

Also, if you are looking for images I would recommend you not to have .txt in your filter. That would seriously ruin the execution.